# Controller Structure / Pattern / Template Question

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

### Introduction

#### Summary:

I am currently trying to refactor my ObjectControllers and want to achieve a certain behaviour. That is that any child class of this abstract object controller inherits all behaviour from it's superclasses. Meaning the Controllable ObjectController is supposed to implement the Selectable behaviour. And modify the target of Controllable aswell as Controllable itself (it's master) according to it's specified behaviour (let's assume it changes a bool).

To clarify further: the `private void method start` is a unity specific hook, the whole purpose of this project is to catch all ui-specific hooks and stack those hook-specific functions on top of eachother using inheritance.

#### Code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace example
{

    public class Example
    {
        public double value;
        public Example(double d) { this.value = d; }
    }

    public abstract class ObjectController
    {
        public Example target;

        internal ObjectController master;
        internal List<System.Delegate> startList;

        public void Initialize(ObjectController o, Example target)
        {
            this.master = o;
            this.target = target;
            startList = new List<System.Delegate>() { };
            master.startList.Add(new System.Action(() => StartPreHook(o)));
        }

        // called before first frame
        public void Start()
        {
            Initialize(this, target);
            foreach (System.Delegate o in startList.ToArray())
            {
                o.DynamicInvoke();
            }
        }

        // abstract funtions to be implemented in derived classes:
        public abstract void StartWrapper();

        // abstract function pre-hooks:
        public abstract void StartPreHook(ObjectController master);
    }

    public class Selectable : ObjectController
    {
        // internal variables
        internal bool isSelected;

        // ui-controls
        public override void StartWrapper()
        {
            isSelected = true;
        }

        // pre-hooks ui-controls
        public override void StartPreHook(ObjectController master)
        {
            StartWrapper();
        }
    }

    public class Controllable : Selectable
    {
        public bool selectable = true;

        public override void StartWrapper()
        {
            if (selectable) new Selectable().Initialize(this, target);
        }

        // pre-hooks ui-controls
        public override void StartPreHook(ObjectController master)
        {
            base.StartPreHook(master);
            StartWrapper();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Invoke example

```
using System;
using example;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Example e = new Example(2.0);
            Controllable i = new Controllable
            {
                target = e
            };
            i.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("is selected: " + i.isSelected.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

#### Current Behaviour

The current code does not overwrite the master ObjectControllers variable, instead it overwrites it's own variable.

Selectable overwrites isselected to true, but only within itself, which is why the example plots false.

#### Intended Behaviour

Calling the function Start() on any child class of ObjectController is supossed to call all start-wrappers from all it's parents (which it does not since it overwrites start-wrappers). I do not want to call `base.StartWrapper()` from any child class. Meaning in the shown example the intended behaviour would print true and not false.

### Fixes

#### Reflection

I tried to fix this behaviour using reflection and dynamically pushing and fetching variable values from master, but I think this is not the right way.

#### List

The most obvious solution would be to implement a List of ObjectControllers in the abstract class and cycle through the functions provided by these. I am pretty sure I could get rid of a couple of wrappers as well that way.

### Question:

Are there any other ways to achieve the intended behaviour? Is there a pattern or design that deals with this? I know how to achieve what I intend to do, however I do not know what the most elegant way would be.

Comment: Can you put some dummy code where you are invoking methods on the child class along with the output you are trying to achieve in both the child and the parent.

Comment: I will further simplify, and remove the unity-dependand stuff.

Comment: I don't know Unity so this may be different, but in your code I do not see a constructor for Controllable with the 2 parameters. My question was specifically around "modify the target of Controllable aswell as Controllable itself (it's master) according to it's specified behaviour (let's assume it changes a bool)." Do you have an example of modifying the behavior on the parent. Maybe, I'm not getting the question.

Comment: See changes above :)

Comment: It is still hard to follow but I'm sure it makes sense in your context. Having debugged the code, it looks like the `StartWrapper()` in Selectable is never being hit and thus `isSelected` inside of it is never set to true. Were you expecting the `isSelected` to be set elsewhere as well. If you put an explicit call in `StartPreHook` or `StartWrapper` inside of `Controllable` to the base implementation of `StartWrapper()` it'll set it to true, but I'm guessing that is not what you want.

Comment: After reading the question, it is not clear to me the **current behavior** and **intended behaviour** of the code you gave as an example. Can you edit that for clarification?

Comment: I added a section on the intended behaviour to clarify further, is that any better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue:

This piece of code was supposed to call the `StartWrapper` of the base class in `base.StartPreHook(master)`:

```
 public override void StartPreHook(ObjectController master)
 {
     base.StartPreHook(master);
     StartWrapper();
 }
```

The definition of `base.StartPreHook(master)` was:

```
// pre-hooks ui-controls
public override void StartPreHook(ObjectController master)
{
    StartWrapper();
}
```

But `StartWrapper()` here is the overwritten `StartWrapper` and not the `StartWrapper` from it's base class.

### Solution:

#### Generic Interface:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace controllertest
{
    public interface IController<T>
    {
        void functionwrapper(T master);
        void initialize();
        T getobj(IController<T> master);
    }
}
```

#### Controller Classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;

namespace controllertest
{
    public class MyExampleBaseClass{
        public double value;
}
    public abstract class Controller<T> : MyExampleBaseClass, IController<T>
    {
        public Queue<Controller<T>> registredcontrollers;
        public T master;
        public void wrapperfunction()
        {
            registredcontrollers = new Queue<Controller<T>>() { };
            this.master = getobj(this);
            registerController(this);
            _functionPreHook(this);
        }

        public void registerController(Controller<T> newController)
        {
            newController.master = master;
            newController.initialize();
            registredcontrollers.Enqueue(newController);
        }

        public abstract void initialize();
        public abstract void _functionPreHook(Controller<T> master);
        public abstract void functionwrapper(T master);
        public abstract T getobj(IController<T> master);
    }

    public abstract class AbstractControllerImplementation<T>:Controller<T>
    {
        public sealed override void _functionPreHook(Controller<T> master)
        {
            // iterate through the registred controllers dynamically:
            var enumerator = registredcontrollers.GetEnumerator();
            int position = -1;
            // enumerators start at index -1 so move to first element:
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            position++;
            // execute first element
            var currentController = enumerator.Current;
            currentController.functionwrapper(this.master);
            int length = registredcontrollers.Count;
            while (position < length)
            {
                // since functionwrapper can modify the queue we have to get a new enumerator:
                enumerator = registredcontrollers.GetEnumerator();
                // advance itterator:
                position++;
                int newEnumPos = -1;
                newEnumPos++;
                enumerator.MoveNext();
                while (newEnumPos < position && newEnumPos < length-1)
                {
                    newEnumPos++;
                    enumerator.MoveNext();
                }
                // call functionwrapper:
                currentController = enumerator.Current;
                currentController.functionwrapper(this.master);
                // adjust length
                length = registredcontrollers.Count;
            }
        }

        public sealed override T getobj(IController<T> master)
        {
            return (T)master;
        }

        public void setAttr<T2>(string name, T obj, T2 value)
        {
            try
            {
                obj.GetType().GetField(name).SetValue(obj, value);
            }
            catch
            {
                this.GetType().GetField(name).SetValue(this, value);
            }
        }

        public void setAttrThisAndObj<T2>(string name, T obj, T2 value)
        {
            try
            {
                obj.GetType().GetField(name).SetValue(obj, value);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            try
            {
                this.GetType().GetField(name).SetValue(this, value);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        public T2 getAttr<T2>(string name, T obj)
        {
            return (T2)obj.GetType().GetField(name).GetValue(obj);
        }
        public T2 getAttrElseSetDefault<T2>(string name, T obj, T2 preset)
        {
            try
            {
                var res = getAttr<T2>(name, obj);
                if (res != null) return res;
                else setAttr(name, obj, preset);
                return preset;
            }
            catch
            {
                setAttr(name, obj, preset);
                return preset;
            }
        }
        public T2 getAttrElseSetDefaultBoth<T2>(string name, T obj, T2 preset)
        {
            try
            {
                var res = getAttr<T2>(name, obj);
                if (res == null) res = preset;
                this.GetType().GetField(name).SetValue(this,res);
                return res;
            }
            catch
            {
                this.GetType().GetField(name).SetValue(this, preset);
                setAttr(name, obj, preset);
                return preset;
            }
        }
    }
    public abstract class ControllerImplementation : AbstractControllerImplementation<ControllerImplementation>
    {
    }
    public class Selectable:ControllerImplementation
    {
        public bool isclicked;
        public bool isselected;

        public override void functionwrapper(ControllerImplementation master)
        {
            if (isSelected()) Console.WriteLine(">>> SELECTABLE FUNCTIONWRAPPER WAS CALLED!");
            if (isClicked()) Console.WriteLine("--- SELECTABLE IS CLICKED");
        }

        public override void initialize()
        {
            this.isclicked=getAttrElseSetDefault<bool>("isclicked", master, false);
            this.isselected = getAttrElseSetDefault<bool>("isselected", master, false);
            if(isSelected()) Console.WriteLine("INITIALIZING SELECTABLE!");
        }
        public bool isClicked()
        {
            try
            { 
                return getAttr<bool>("isclicked", master);
            }
            catch
            {
                return this.isclicked;
            }
        }
        public bool isSelected()
        {
            try
            {
                return getAttr<bool>("isselected", master);
            }
            catch
            {
                return this.isselected;
            }
        }
    }

    public class Controllable : Selectable
    {
        public bool canBeSelected;
        public bool canBeControlled;
        public override void functionwrapper(ControllerImplementation master)
        {
            if (isSelected()) Console.WriteLine(">>> CONTROLLABLE FUNCTIONWRAPPER WAS CALLED!");
            if (CanBeSelected()) {
                if (isSelected()) Console.WriteLine("--- CONTROLLABLE IS SELECTABLE, REGISTERING COMPONENT!");
                var s = new Selectable();
                master.registerController(s);
            }

        }
        public override void initialize()
        {
            this.canBeSelected = getAttrElseSetDefault("canBeSelected", master, true);
            this.canBeControlled = getAttrElseSetDefault("canBeControlled", master, true);
            if (isSelected()) Console.WriteLine("INITIALIZING CONTROLLABLE!");
        }
        public bool CanBeSelected()
        {
            try
            {
                return getAttr<bool>("canBeSelected", master);
            }
            catch
            {
                return this.canBeSelected;
            }
        }
        public bool CanBeControlled()
        {
            try
            {
                return getAttr<bool>("canBeControlled", master);
            }
            catch
            {
                return this.canBeControlled;
            }
        }
    }
    public class presetMaskExample : Controllable
    {
        public override void initialize()
        {
            if (isSelected()) Console.WriteLine("INITIALIZING PRINTSTUFF");
            if (isSelected()) Console.WriteLine("setting canBeControlled and canBeSelected to true");
            setAttrThisAndObj("canBeSelected", master, true);
            setAttrThisAndObj("canBeControlled", master, true);
        }
    }
    public class PrintStuff : presetMaskExample
    {
        public string printstuff;
        public override void functionwrapper(ControllerImplementation master)
        {
            if (isSelected()) Console.WriteLine(">>> PRINTSTUFF FUNCTIONWRAPPER WAS CALLED!");
            if (CanBeControlled())
            {
                if (isSelected()) Console.WriteLine(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> PRINTSTUFF CAN BE CONTROLLED!");
                Console.WriteLine(this.printstuff);
            }
        }
        public override void initialize()
        {
            if (isSelected()) Console.WriteLine("INITIALIZING P_PRINTSTUFF");
            var mask = new presetMaskExample();
            master.registerController(mask);
            if(printstuff==null) printstuff = getAttrElseSetDefaultBoth("printstuff", master, "LALALALALA!!!");
        }
    }

    public class PrintMe : ControllerImplementation
    {
        public bool allowOthersToPrint;
        private Dictionary<string, string> values;
        public override void functionwrapper(ControllerImplementation master)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(">>> PRINT_ME FUNCTIONWRAPPER WAS CALLED!");
            if (AllowOthersToPrint())
            {
                foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp in values)
                {
                    var i = new PrintStuff();
                    i.printstuff=(kvp.Key + "   |    " + kvp.Value);
                    i.canBeControlled = true;
                    master.registerController(i);
                }
            }

        }

        public override void initialize()
        {
            values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Random rng = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            {
                bool succeded = false;
                var keybuffer = new byte[7];
                var valuebuffer = new byte[55];
                while (!succeded)
                {
                    succeded = true;
                    rng.NextBytes(keybuffer);
                    rng.NextBytes(keybuffer);
                    rng.NextBytes(valuebuffer);
                    rng.NextBytes(valuebuffer);
                    var k = new string(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(keybuffer));
                    var v = new string(UTF32Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(valuebuffer));
                    try
                    {
                        values.Add(k, v);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        succeded = false;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        public bool AllowOthersToPrint()
        {
            try
            {
                return getAttr<bool>("allowOthersToPrint", master);
            }
            catch
            {
                return this.allowOthersToPrint;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Invoke Solution:

```
using System;

namespace controllertest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Basic Example using inheritance:");
            var test = new Controllable
            {
                // initialize in controllable does not preset it's values, so all bools are false by default
                canBeControlled = true,
                canBeSelected = true,
                isselected = true
            };
            test.wrapperfunction();
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            Console.WriteLine("Basic Example partial-hierachy / masking parents:");
            var mask = new presetMaskExample();
            mask.isselected = true;
            mask.wrapperfunction();
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            Console.WriteLine("Basic Example using a mask as base to build a new controller:");
            var DoesPrint = new PrintStuff();
            DoesPrint.wrapperfunction();
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            Console.WriteLine("Basic Example registering not derived components:");
            var print = new PrintMe();
            print.allowOthersToPrint = true;
            print.wrapperfunction();
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        }
    }
}
```

### Issues:

The new controller class uses reflection to set and get fields from it's master, I really dislike this part, but I failed to see how else I could achieve the implemented behaviour